# mysql fetch previous N record from given ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to fetch previous 5 records from given ID. For example

ID -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

if I give ID 2 -> output should be (2,1,10,9,8)
if I give ID 9 -> output should be (9,8,7,6,5)

Please help me to resolve

Comment: Do you actually have a database table?

Comment: you can use limit for the seconf example. for the first one you will need two queries

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it

```sql
(SELECT *FROM table1
 WHERE id <= 2 -- given id goes here (2, 9 etc)
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 5)
LIMIT 5
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=52b6c191df97bd110976b27f297b6260) demo

Comment: thanks peterm..it works as expected. Thanks for your query

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Consider accepting the answer [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232667)